# Meaning of 冷やかし上等

Tags: meaning

From what I understand the word can be used to describe teasing, window shopping, etc, but I am not quite sure what it means in this context.

「そんなあなたにぴったりのこのコーナー！　題して」

「『どうやったらそんなに一途な恋を見つけられるんですか！？』**冷やかし上等**！　ラブマスターの経験から学ぶ出会いのテクニック」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "冷やかし" for "このコーナー(title: 『どうやったらそんなに一途な恋を見つけられるんですか！？』冷やかし上等！　ラブマスターの経験から学ぶ出会いのテクニック)".

"冷やかす" doesn't mean "window shopping" but rather "looking around for products with no intention of buying."
"冷やかし" is not only used against shops, but also against events and projects.

Thus, in this context.
'Even if you don't feel like watching this section closely, come on over! It's no problem at all !
There are nuances like.